# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0 on redhat

Tags: c++, c, address-sanitizer

I am normally using valgrind for my c/c++ programs but people have been recommending address sanitizer, so I wanted to test it out, but im having problems linking against it on a redhat system.

I got the following code:

$ cat heap-use-after-free.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int *array = new int[100];
  delete [] array;
  return array[argc];  // BOOM
}
```

compiling like:

$ g++ -O -g -fsanitize=address heap-use-after-free.cpp

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On a redhat where I have installed libasan

```
sudo yum install libasan
[sudo] password for dingdongsong: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
rh-network-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-7-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                           | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-7-custom-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 1.0 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-7-epel-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                                       | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-7-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-7-rhscl-1-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-7-thirdparty-oracle-java-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-extras-7-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-7-prod                                                                                                                                                                                                              | 1.5 kB  00:00:00     
Package libasan-4.9.2-6.2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

With the following libasan shared objects:

$ locate libasan

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libasan.a
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libasan.so
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/32/libasan_preinit.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libasan.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libasan_preinit.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libasan.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libasan.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/32/libasan_preinit.o
/usr/lib64/libasan.so.1
/usr/lib64/libasan.so.1.0.0
```

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I just tested this in a CentOS 7 Docker container and it worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

Please install the additional libraries,

```
yum install libasan libubsan
```

Ref: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1303766

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's looking for an earlier version of the library than you have. Try doing this and see what it says:

```
sudo yum install /usr/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0
```

Also, are you sure that your version of the `gcc-c++` package is up-to-date?

The version of the `libasan` package I have in a CentOS 7 container that works is this: `libasan-4.8.5-36.el7_6.2.x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently on a CentOS 7 system with gcc 4.8.5 and was running into this same issue. I found an rpm at https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/7.7.1908/x86_64/Packages/libasan-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.html and was able to get up and running with it.